# VBA Receiving Compile error - Out of Memory

Tags: memory, compilation, structure

I have created a Main Userform that incorporates, multipage many fields and buttons and those link to various other userforms and worksheets and fields. I have reached a point where when I try to F5 I get an "Compile Error - Out of Memory"

I'm newer to troubleshooting these kinds of issues and granted I did not have a plan when I started in terms of structuring the forms and modules or what this would grow into.

This specific issue came having a Page that has a scroll feature that looks at a worksheet and pulls in records into various comboboxes based on a status of Open, closed, Hold etc. Each record is retrieving approx 7-8 fields and each page has approx 50 records that could display except closed which has to have enough for all.

I have read a couple things about ending Object to = nothing and enabling some advanced Windows to allow more memory allocation. I feel like maybe its a combination of structure and not clearing memory when i move around the tool. Any advise help or resources you could point me towards?

Attached is the Error, VBA project tree and a screen shot of one of the multipage items being pulled into the userform from the worksheet. (there will be multiple pages beside "open" that could have up to 100 or more records.

Thanks again,

Attached are Project Structure, error message, and userform-multipage screenshot example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I was able to move past this, My issue was that I had a very bulky form that called a lot of textboxes and combo boxes upon initialization. This obviously required a lot of memory to render all this fields at once. Hence the error.

Solution: I re-thought the form and decided to use a list box and upon selecting a record from the list the fields I needed populate in the box below the list. This allowed me to go from hundreds of boxes to 12. This also was coupled that I had multi- page within a page. Sometimes you just need to take a step back and rethink and restructure your plan.